# Understanding the universe as a 3-dimensional surface

Tags: universe, alien-geometry

When thinking about the shape of the universe in my story I have been looking into it being a 3-manifold. As I understand it, space would be a 3-dimensional surface and for a small scale observer space would seem flat but if somehow it could be viewed from outside its shape would be curved.

Something I am not able to visualise or probably that I don't understand is if there is a thickness which would be a much shorter length than moving in other directions? So if you moved across the circumference of the surface/shape you would either return to where you started or move in a seemingly endless path looping around the shape but if you moved at 90 degrees to the circumference,  would it be a much shorter distance to travel and if so, what would happen there? Would space curve back on itself?

Two of the easiest topologies to imagine this surface on is a hollow sphere and a torus, in this image the surface of the torus would be 3-dimensional space time and the grey cross section area is the depth or thickness of space which I am wondering if it would be a much shorter distance to reach than taking other paths and what would happen to space when you reach there?

[image]

Edits have been made to the question to correct parts which were mentioned in the comments.

Comment: "So if you moved across the surface/shape you would either return to where you started or move in a seemingly endless path looping around the shape . . ." I don't follow this 100%. Maybe put a picture.

Comment: "would space curve so that there is no "outside" of the space that is visible or accessible." I don't follow this either.

Comment: A *surface* by definition has no depth. You may be confusing it with a sheet of paper, but a sheet of paper is actually a three-dimensional object, it just has a much smaller thickness than its width and length. (And, while you *can* view spacetime as a 4-dimensional manifold embedded in some higher dimensionality manifold, such a view is neither required nor useful in any way. For all the practical purposes of physics, the 4-dimensional spacetime is not embedded in 5-, 6- or higher-dimension space, and such an embedding won't simplify physics at all; in fact, it would complicate it.)

Comment: A simple example of how "surface depth" might have no meaning is the manifold of heights and weights of people. Every point on the manifold is a pair of numbers (height, weight). All the possibilities knit together to form a 2d surface. But there is no perpendicular direction to this manifold.

Comment: @AlexP I not fully following sorry. I have heard people saying the surface is embedded, which I didn't understand but in my visualisation I don't see or need other dimensions the curved space has that shape but nothing outside matters or exists.

Comment: Wow I completely misunderstood the question if this is what you are talking about. But I still don't follow ". . . which I am wondering if it would be a much shorter distance to reach than taking other paths and what would happen to space when you reach there?"

Comment: @Daron I may need to re-word that, what I wrote earlier and what we talked about earlier was a better description, moving around the circumference in any directions would take longer than moving at 90 degrees to the circumference through the "thickness" but as AlexP in comments and Tanner Swett in their answer said, the surface thickness may zero or close to it and it is a direction/dimension that is not accessible or have any meaning.

Comment: @JarredJones Do you mean it would take longer to move around the circumference from one side of the sphere than it would take to move from the outermost part of the "thickness" to the innermost part?

Comment: @Daron yes, or from any part of the thickness to the outer or inner part. You could change your answer if you have more thoughts about it.

Comment: Yes, if the "thickness" dimension exists it is always considered to be small -- too small to see. If it was large enough to see it would be obvious that we live in a 4d space. Since the thickness is small it would take no time at all to go from the inner surface of the sphere to the outside. Traveling in this direction would be more like "a special type of vibration" than actual travel.

Comment: The kind of thing this extra dimension might explain -- not this exactly -- is that a particle on the outer surface seems to be an electron, but one on the inner surface seems to be a positron. Moving from the inside to the outside does not look like physical movement, it looks like changing the properties of a particle.

Comment: @Daron To be honest the idea of a 2d surface has put me off using a 3-manifold for the moment, I am thinking more about other shapes for finite space and ways to deal with the edge and no centre.

Comment: Hmm. . .  well any universe not shaped like a 3-manifold will look very different from our own. In any case I think we have reached the limit of helpful discussion without drawing labelled diagrams and pointing to parts of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If space really is a 3-dimensional manifold (which is what most theories of physics assume), then its "thickness," in the sense that you're talking about, is exactly 0. Even if we assume that there's some direction which is perpendicular to all three of our ordinary everyday dimensions, it's impossible to move in that direction, because the amount of distance available in that direction is 0.

According to Wikipedia, [string theory may predict that there are more than 3 spatial dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=String_theory&oldid=1065176932#Extra_dimensions), and Wikipedia mentions two possibilities for how this might work. One of the possibilities is called "compactification," and my understanding of this is that space *does* have a thickness, but the thickness is extremely tiny (maybe a few picometers, I dunno). These dimensions would curve back on themselves, so if you were to move in the direction of the thickness of space, you'd quickly end up back where you started.

The other possibility that Wikipedia mentions is "that the observable universe is a four-dimensional subspace of a higher dimensional space." In other words, the observable universe is a thin slice of something bigger, and I don't know if the thickness of that slice is 0, or something greater than 0.

Comment: zero or close to, thickness sounds crazy and confusing lol, You mentioning string theory made me think of Brane theory, that also says it is very thin although there are thick branes but so far I haven't found out how thick they are. Having zero or close to, thickness makes me think of the Holographic principle or how we view the CMB.

Comment: Well, having zero thickness is the simplest possible situation, because it means that the universe _really is_ 3-dimensional, just like it seems to be. Having non-zero thickness would mean that the universe has at least one hidden dimension that hasn't been discovered yet, and I would call _that_ pretty "crazy and confusing."

Comment: I still don't really understand zero thickness being 3-dimensional, for holographic principle all information encoded onto a 2d surface kind of makes sense but something being 2d when viewed from outside but is actually 3d and infinite inside is hard to get my head around.

Comment: I don't think _anyone_ fully understands the holographic principle, not even theoretical physicists! So if I were you, I wouldn't worry about the holographic principle at all. As for why zero thickness would correspond to being 3-dimensional... well, let me try to explain it with an analogy. Is a sheet of paper (a _real_ sheet of paper) 2-dimensional or 3-dimensional? (cont'd)

Comment: At first glance, paper kind of seems like it's 2-dimensional. However, paper actually has a nonzero thickness, which means that it's really 3-dimensional after all. But if paper really did have exactly zero thickness, that would make it truly 2-dimensional. The thickness of paper provides an extra dimension, but if it didn't have that thickness, then it'd just be 2-dimensional. We can apply the same reasoning to space, but we have to add 1 to each number. (cont'd)

Comment: So, is space 3-dimensional or 4-dimensional? At first glance, space seems like it's 3-dimensional. But _maybe_ it actually has a nonzero thickness, which means that it's really 4-dimensional after all. But if space really does have exactly zero thickness, that makes it truly 3-dimensional. The thickness of space, if it exists, provides an extra dimension; but if it doesn't have that thickness, then it's just 3-dimensional.

Comment: I only like the 2d surface and link to black holes in holographic theory the rest seems like a strange idea but they do talk about an infinite radius 2d surface. Inside the 3-dimensional manifold is space infinite or finite? I am setting the zero thickness surface aside as it is still confusing. when inside 3d space does the hollow sphere shape still exist and have the infinite/finite volume, so if it was infinite, its circumference would be infinite and I hate to say thickness again but its thickness is infinite also?

Comment: @JarredJones I second that you should not worry about the holographic principle. It has nothing to do with this talk of the universe being a manifold. And no one understands the holographic principle anyway.

Comment: @Daron I am only using it as a visual comparison of the 3d universe being a 2d surface, so like the CMB if you viewed the universe from outside all of the superclusters at depth will be overlapped in a single 2d image.

Comment: @JarredJones It is an unhelpful visual comparison because the two things are very different.

Answer (score 1):

**Folding Space**

[image]

In the Sci-Fi Business, What you are talking about is called folding space. This is a type of mumbo-jumbo where we explain the existence of wormholes or faster than light travel by pretending the universe (three or four dimensional) exists in some larger space, the same way a sheet of paper exists in three-dimensional space.

Even though there is a speed limit on the paper -- hence a minimum time to travel from one corner to the other -- you can zip from one corner to the other if you have a magic sci-fi engine that bends the sheet to put the corners on top of each other. To creatures living on the sheet with no conception of the perpendicular direction, this would look like some sort of wormhole.

Of course this is all scifi mumbo-jumbo. In General Relativity the universe and its matter is described as a four dimensional manifold. There is a whole field of maths called differential geometry, which centres around how to refer to such objects using properties inherent in the manifold itself, rather than them existing in some larger space. Under this mathematical framework it doesn't even make sense to move in the perpendicular direction.

You don't even need an ambient dimension to describe wormholes. A universe with a wormhols is just a different type of 4d shape to a universe without a manifold. The difference is there is a tunnel in one and not the other. We don't need to suppose a higher ambient dimension to describe the tunnel.

Comment: I am not talking about wormholes or manipulating a manifold, the topology of the universe in these theories is a manifold, like a sphere, torus or many other types with the surface being space.

Comment: You are talking about  a "3 dimensional curved surface". The mathematical version of that is just a 3-dimensional manifold.

Comment: Going off yours and AlexP's comments above I still don't understand how to visualise that without comparing it to a hollow sphere or other shape?

Comment: @JarredJones There is nothing wrong with imagining it as a hollow shape. For example a 2-d sphere with matter moving around it, and the matter causes bulges in the surface. You just have to keep in mind the space inside or outside the sphere has no physical meaning.

Comment: But then comparing it to a 2d sphere do we not have that "thickness" issue of it being a shorter distance than across the sphere, or have I missed something still?

Comment: @JarredJones Do you mean it would be faster to travel from North to South pole in a straight line through the center of the sphere, than to travel around the circumference?

Comment: Yes but inside the sphere is empty/ non existent, so it would be traveling that surface segment north to south/ at a 90 degree angle to the circumference.

Comment: "traveling that surface segment north to south/ at a 90 degree angle to the circumference." I don't understand what this means.

Comment: I think OP is talking about the shape of the universe whereby Ω > 1 or positive curvature, maybe.